# Virtual paths to actual physical files using Routing in Asp.Net and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, routes

I use Asp.Net 4 C# with Routing.

I use Routing to re-route URL's to actual physical files. My code is pretty identical to [this one](http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/).

My aim is to have images `src` attribute created using a custom Route but to have the physical path for the image in a different folder.

Example output Route:

```
<img alt="" src="/cdn/img/cms/e71e75ef-4906-4d04-8da5-bd459c7b9205/titolo-image.jpg"/>
```

The phisical path:

```
/cdn/img/cms/images/large/e71e75ef-4906-4d04-8da5-bd459c7b9205.jpg
```

Everything works great on CASSINI when testing on a local enviroment with Visual Studio 2010, but as soon as the website runs in production enviroment wich use IIS 7.5 the image `src` result not found.

**I suppose IIS is not handling the request for a static file .jpg in the same way of a .Net Page.**

I would like to know what are my options to solve this situation.

Here the code I use to extend the Routing for images..

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;

```
namespace WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Handler Custom Class for Asp.Net Routing. Routing URL's (Virtual paths) to actual physical files.
    /// <remarks>Resource at: http://www.phpvs.net/2009/08/06/aspnet-mvc-how-to-route-to-images-or-other-file-types/</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            string filename = requestContext.RouteData.Values["RowGuid"] as string;
            string size = requestContext.RouteData.Values["Size"] as string;
            string imageType = requestContext.RouteData.Values["ImageType"] as string;

            bool hasFileName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename);
            bool hasSize =
                size == "large" ||
                size == "medium" ||
                size == "small";
            bool hasImageType =
                imageType == "jpg" ||
                imageType == "bmp" ||
                imageType == "gif" ||
                imageType == "png";

            if (!hasFileName || !hasSize || !hasImageType)
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = GetContentType(requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString());

                // Find physical path to image.
                string filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Cdn/Cms/Images/" + size + "/" + filename + "." + imageType);

                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private static string GetContentType(String path)
        {
            switch (Path.GetExtension(path))
            {
                case ".bmp": return "Image/bmp";
                case ".gif": return "Image/gif";
                case ".jpg": return "Image/jpeg";
                case ".png": return "Image/png";
                default: break;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suspect right, you need to make sure you have defined in your web.config that IIS should be routing through JPG requests to your new custom handler.

[This article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis-7-and-above/) looks like it's a good introduction guide to the Integrated Pipeline in IIS7 and how you can customize it to your needs. It will just be a case of registering yoour handler in the web.config and setting it so that all *.jpg paths go to your handler.

Comment: it is smt I can do just in web.config, or I have to modify smt directly in IIS 7? Thanks for your time.

Comment: IIS 7 typically stores all site config in web.config (you can store it elsewhere if you need to), so you should be fine to just edit that.

Comment: Thanks PirateKitten i was able to make it work.. but I have a small problem here my question, maybe you know the answer many thank http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810435/how-to-apply-a-custom-handlers-to-only-specific-folder

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice from PirateKitten, I was able to solve my problem, here the working code in my web.config:

```
   <system.webServer>
...

        <handlers>
            <add name="Cms-ImageRouteHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="*" type="WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing.ImageRouteHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
...
```