# How to apply a custom handlers to only specific folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, handler

I use Asp.Net 4 C# and IIS 7.5.

In web.config I was able to apply my handler with success (code below) as you can see  `path="*.jpg"` let the handler operate in any folder of my website.

I need instead apply this handler `to all .jpg request but ONLY in a specific folder`, in my case `/Cdn/Cms/Images/`

So I update to `path="/Cdn/Cms/Images/*.jpg"` but the handler does not apply.

I tried many times with different paths but now way.

How can I apply a handler to only a specific folder?

Thanks for your time on this.

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806414/virtual-paths-to-actual-physical-files-using-routing-in-asp-net-and-iis)

```
   <system.webServer>
...
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

        <handlers>
            <add name="Cms-ImageRouteHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="*" type="WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing.ImageRouteHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the `/Cdn/Cms/images` folder structure in your website folder and then create a web.config in that folder with just the following:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
            <add name="Cms-ImageRouteHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="*" type="WebProject.Cms.BusinessLogics.SEO.Routing.ImageRouteHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You can then remove it from your main site's web.config. See if that works.

Comment: I created a new web.config as you suggested in /cdn/ and now is works, once again many thanks for your help and suggestions.